# "this" is not returning module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js

With the code below using Node.js v11.13.0, I receive the error that `this.say is not a function`.

```
/* utils.js */
module.exports = {
  test: function() {
    this.say('Hello.');
  },

  say: function(text) {
    console.log(text);
  }
};
```

```
/* index.js */
const {test} = require('./utils.js');
test();
```

When I log `this` with the function declared using `function() {`, it seems to return the global environmental object created by Node.js. If I use an arrow function instead, it returns an empty object.

Why isn't `this` returning `module.exports`?

*The code is only an example, I'm not actually using it.*

Comment: The value of `this` is determined by how a function is called. You're calling the function "naked", with no object reference, so `this` takes the default value (the global object).

Comment: If you wrote `const utils = require("./utils.js"); utils.test();` it would work as you expect.

Comment: `utils` name suggests that they are utility functions that are supposed to be used separately. If this is so, it's a mistake to tie them to `this`.

Comment: @estus I use one of them to print to the console using custom styling so I don't have to copy and paste the escape codes for the colors and format the time each `console.log()`. This is the only one others depend on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has since been resolved by properly using `module.exports` instead. Part of the confusion behind this question was the fact that Visual Studio Code says `this` in my function should be `module.exports`. If I needed to use it multiple times I'd create a class, but I see no use now.

Thank you for the clarification and suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

First off: **why** are you trying to do this? You're in Node, so there is literally no reason for any of your code to look up what the node construct is. It should only care about being able to find the things *you* wrote.

Secondly, you're declaring a plain object, not a class instance, so the `this` keyword will *never* point to that variable. It can only ever point to the owner of whatever the current execution scope is.

If you want to return `module.exports`, then just... do. Either directly, which would be weird, or by at least capturing your export as a real thing first:

```
const mything = {
  test: function() {
    mything.say("hello");
  },
  say(text) {
    console.log(text);
  }
};

module.exports = mything;
```

But from your code, that's not what you want. What you *want* is a real class:

```
class MyThing {
  test() {
    this.say('Hello.');
  }

  say(text) {
    console.log(text);
  }
};

module.exports = MyThing;
```

Which you should then call as:

```
const MyThing = require("./my-thing.js"); 
let mything = new MyThing();
mything.test();
```